Replacing a Crystal Oscillator with External Clock
I am designing a board around the ESP32-C3 MCU. For the reference clock in the HW Design Guidelines, it mentions to use an external crystal oscillator with compensation capacitors.
My question is whether I can substitute in a ECS-TXO-2520-33-400-AN-TR instead of the oscillator? The guidelines do not mention anything about this, nor what to do with the other pin if using a TCXO. For this I put a depopulated capacitor so that I can ground it, put a cap, or do anything needed based on testing.
Really looking forward to hearing feedback regarding this!! Thank you in advance.



That looks right. Leave XTAL_N open. Keep the oscillator+R10  close to the ESP.
The oscillator has a pullup on the TRI input so that pin also can be left open.

I have no experience on the C3 variant, but especially the S2 variant suggests the use of DC blocking capacitor around 50pF before feeding the XTAL_P pin. Sometimes when used with an oscillator, chips intended for crystal operation may require AC coupling and lower amplitude than 3.3V. And this knowledge is not available in current documentation.

@Justme The forums seem to (to me) indicate it's okay without, maybe, but it wouldn't hurt to put an 0402 0Ω resistor/ capacitor in series just in case if it can't be confirmed with Espressif.

@Justme, thanks for the heads up on that. Was wondering if some of the other documentation offered insight on what to do when switching to oscillator. Will use Spehro's suggestion and use an 0402 in case the AC coupling is needed!

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany, great idea, will put that in. Just to be safe! This is prototype and will remove anything unnecessary. Thanks for also giving some feedback regarding if I could leave it floating!

This ESP schematic shows XTAL_N as the input, so the output _P is floating and not required except as a test point.

@D.A.S. XTAL_P is the input.  I think the designer has connected the crystal "output" to the chip "input" or something of that ilk.

Confirmed "XTAL_P is typically an input pin for the oscillator."

Is a 5 yr possible aging adequate for the 10 ppm spec? https://i.sstatic.net/cwm4dBOg.png  not including vibration or shock errors.
